# How to communicate to a gsm modem in c++ using IOKit?

Tags: c++, xcode, at-command, iokit

I am trying to create a program in c++ on xcode to communicate to the gsm modem and send sms through AT comands. I haven' t found much on the net. Here is the code that I have written till now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xlnt/xlnt.hpp>
#include <xlnt/xlnt_config.hpp>
#include <IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOTypes.h>
#include <IOReturn.h>
#include <IOKitKeys.h>
#include <iokitmig.h>
#include <OSMessageNotification.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <paths.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/serial/IOSerialKeys.h>
#include <IOKit/IOBSD.h>

#define LOCAL_ECHO
#ifdef LOCAL_ECHO
#define kOKResponseString “AT\r\r\nOK\r\n”
#else
#define kOKResponseString “\r\nOK\r\n”
#define kATCommandString        "AT\r"
#define kMyErrReturn            -1
enum {
kNumRetries = 3
};

static struct termios gOriginalTTYAttrs;



int main()
{
char path;
char text;

int fileDescriptor;
kern_return_t kernResult;
io_iterator_t serialPortIterator;
char deviceFilePath[MAXPATHLEN];
kernResult = MyFindModems(&serialPortIterator);
kernResult = MyGetModemPath(serialPortIterator, deviceFilePath,
                        sizeof(deviceFilePath));
IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator); // Release the iterator.
// Open the modem port, initialize the modem, then close it.
if (!deviceFilePath[0])
{
printf("No modem port found.\n");
return EX_UNAVAILABLE;
}
fileDescriptor = OpenSerialPort(deviceFilePath);
if (fileDescriptor == kMyErrReturn)
{
return EX_IOERR;
}
if (MyInitializeModem(fileDescriptor))
{
printf("Modem initialized successfully.\n");
}
else {
printf("Could not initialize modem.\n");
}
MyCloseSerialPort(fileDescriptor);
printf("Modem port closed.\n");
return EX_OK;
```

It's giving me an error "use of undeclared identifier MyFindModems" and all the other fuctions that start with "My".
Here is the documentation to which I refer: http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWSerial/WorkingWithSerial.pdf

Comment: Hi Aleeeee, It seems the guide shows it backwards. 
You have to define MyFindModems, which it describes on page 11 before you can use it.

Comment: Hi @Wisienkas thanks for the answer. You're right! Now I am gonna check what it's written. Do I have to include the part inside main function? I believe no